# How to fix stack index in stacked bar

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

My expectation is I want the stack A always in first index, next index is B, and the C always the last stack

How can I do it?

Current seeing
[image]

Current configuration:

```js
{
  chart: {
    type: "bar",
    stacked: true,
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: "a",
      data: [70, 0],
      color: "#32a852", // green
      index: 1,
    },
    {
      name: "b",
      data: [25, 0],
      color: "#861086", // purple
      index: 2,
    },
    {
      name: "c",
      data: [5, 0],
      color: "#B7B7B7", // gray
      index: 3,
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack for `bar` appears to be reversed by default. You can set `reversedStacks` to `false` like this:

```js
yAxis: {
  // ...
  reversedStacks: false
},
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/dg81s4L2/).